# I get an exception when trying to find smallest value array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find the smallest value in an array of integers, but when I do I get an arrayindexoutofbounds on a place which, as far as I know, there shouldn't be a counting of array-index, only a comparison of the index and a min-value. 
Part of code in question underneath:

```
    }
    System.out.println(sum);

    int minste=tall[0]; 
    for (int i : tall){ 
        if(tall[i]<tall[0]){ //This is where the exception is made. But why?
        minste=tall[i]; 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(minste);
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you understand from your last post about the enhanced for loop? `i` is not an index.

Answer (score 3):

`i` is already an element, just use it. No need to `tall[i]`:

`if(i < minste) {`

This loop means: "For each `int` in `tall`".

In order to better understand the *enhanced loop*, think about it this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tall.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(tall[i]); 
}
```

Will print the same thing as:

```
for(int i : tall) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

That's why it's recommended to use a meaningful name for the variable, instead of `i`, use `item`, so it'll be like "for each `item` in `tall`"...

Alternative solution to find the smallest value:

1. Use [`Arrays#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29)
2. Return the first element in the array

Comment: This will only get rid of the exception, but not solve the issue. It wouldn't get you the minimum element.

Comment: @RohitJain - I think the edit I made should fix that.

Comment: Thanks, now I understood the enhanced for-loop alot better too!

Answer (score 2):

When you're using the `for-each` loop, why use the indexes?

```
if(tall[i]<tall[0]){
```

`tall[i]` - gives the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because `i` is an element in your array and not an index value. And that value `i` is definitely more than the length of your array.

All you need to do is thi

```
int minste = tall[0]; 
for (int i : tall) { 
    if(i < minste) { 
        minste = i; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using for-each loop, but try to use `i` as a index.
To work properly change your code to

```
int minste = tall[0]; 
for (int i : tall)
{ 
    if(i < minste)
    {
        minste = i; 
    }
}
```

or

```
int minste = tall[0]; 
for (int i = 0; i<tall.length; i++)
{ 
    if(tall[i] < minste)
    {
        minste = tall[i]; 
    }
}
```